# How to develop smart textfield (like Google Search box) which on entering text give suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

I am working for a insurance company. I need to create a textfield (like Google Search box) in my project which give suggestion on entering text. The suggestion text should come from online web service or third party.

Comment: Search about autocomplete on google, may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this JQuery Plugin [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) [JqueryUI Autocomplete](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_autocomplete.htm) You can find the tutorial of using it with ASP.Net [here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1207/autocompletion-with-jquery-plugin.aspx)

Also check this one: [Complete.ly](http://complete-ly.appspot.com/)

Comment: Thnxx.. Seems like Autocomplete JqueryUI will be the one that i was looking for, My only concern is that instead of showing available tag in suggestion from javascript array variable I need to show these suggestion from external api or third party web service.. Anyway thanks